# GridBooleanColumn with data first by 0 and 1 but no true and false

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my db I have a column Actif with values 0 and 1 (false and true)

I tried to use a column. Boolean with my db values 0 and 1 ... but it doesn't work.

```
{
    xtype: 'booleancolumn',
    dataIndex: 'Actif',
    text: 'MyBooleanColumn',
    falseText: 'Non',
    trueText: 'Oui'
}
```

Help me please :)

My Model

```
Ext.define('ModuleGestion.model.UtilisateursApplicatifs', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    {
        name: 'Nom'
    },
    {
        name: 'Prenom'
    },
    {
        name: 'Identification'
    },
    {
        name: 'MotDePasse'
    },
    {
        name: 'IUtilisateurApplicatif'
    },
    {
        name: 'FonctionRepertoire'
    },
    {
        name: 'FonctionAnimation'
    },
    {
        name: 'FonctionFormation'
    },
    {
        name: 'FonctionAdministration'
    },
    {
        name: 'Actif'
    }
]});
```

**the solution is delete the double quote of the return of the values :**

```
$resultat = json_encode($resultat ); 
$resultat = str_replace('"Actif":"0"', '"Actif":0', $resultat); 
$resultat = str_replace('"Actif":"1"', '"Actif":1', $resultat);
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: when he reads the value that the display does not match 0 = false and 1 = true but still true

Comment: Edit your post to show your model definition, the problem is likely there.

Comment: thx done @EvanTrimboli my model is in my original post

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation and for work with 0 and 1 from db I use not boolean column. From db I send 0 and 1, in my column renderer I check this and make some conversions. Check my example(here's actioncolumn - it's for show icons in cells). It's one way to decision your situation.
My view:

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
width: 55,
align: 'center',
dataIndex: 'Actif',
menuDisabled: 'true'
text: '',
sortable: false,
fixed: 'true',
renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
    if (value == '0') {
        //some code
    }
    else {
        //some code
    }
},
getTip: function (value, metadata, record) {
    if (value == '0') {
        return 'here 0';
    } else {
        return 'here 1';
    }
}
```

You don't need to change model.

In your example I think you should add type of you'r field in model.

[here's example](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.grid.column.Boolean.html)

```
  { name: 'Actif', type: 'boolean' }
```

Comment: Ok thx but With 0 and 1... the render is always the trueText (with the booleancolum) then i supose is the same with other similar column

Comment: check your server side, mayde you send always true!? You can work not with boolean, 0 and 1 should work.

Comment: it works with : $resultat = json_encode($resultat ); $resultat = str_replace('"Actif":"0"', '"Actif":0', $resultat); $resultat = str_replace('"Actif":"1"', '"Actif":1', $resultat);